# Most elegant solution to chain asynchronous calls in java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, asynchronous

I'm currently developing the presentation layer of an android app.

The api which I'm using looks something like this:

```
public interface errorInterface{
    public void onError(String reason);
}

public interface if1 extends errorInterface{
    public void dataReceived1(Data data);
}
public interface if2 extends errorInterface{
    public void dataReceived2(Data data);
}   

public void fetchData1(if1 receiver) {}
public void fetchData2(if2 receiver) {}
```

That is; to fetch data you provide a receiver which will receieve the result of the operation sometime in the future.

This works very well when you need to call only one method at a time, but now I have reached the point when I need to call 10+ such methods in one go, and they need to execute one at a time.

How can I solve this in a flexible and elegant way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me make sure I understand.. you have a series of interfaces `if1`, `if2`.. `ifn` and you want them all to be able to process the data received.

First of all, it would be best if `if1`, `if2`, etc were all the same interface with your two basic methods: `public void dataReceived(Data d)` and `public void onError(String reason)`.  With that, you can simply pass a `List` or `Collection` of your receivers to `fetchData` and it can iterate over the collection and call `dataReceived(d)` on each one.

If, for whatever reason, that's unworkable, I would try an adapter to coax them into a similar interface for `fetchData`.  For example:

```
public interface DataReceiver extends ErrorInterface {
  public void dataReceived(Data d); 
  //or just scrap the ErrorInterface all together and make these into 1 interface
}

public class AbstractIFAdapter<T extends ErrorInterface> implements DataReceiver {
  private T target;
  public AbstractIFAdapter(T target) { this.target = target);
  public void onError(String reason) { target.onError(reason); }
  protected T getTarget() { return target; }
}

public class IF1Adapter extends AbstractIFAdapter<IF1> {
  public IF1Adapter(IF1 target) { super(target); }
  public dataReceived(Data d) { getTarget().dataReceived1(d); }
}

public class IF2Adapter extends AbstractIFAdapter<IF2> {
  public IF2Adapter(IF2 target) { super(target); }
  public dataReceived(Data d) { getTarget().dataReceived2(d); }
}
```

Now with that in place, we can do something like this:

```
List<DataReceiver> dataReceivers = new ArrayList<DataReceiver>();
dataReceivers.add(new IF1Adapter(someIf1Implementation));
dataReceivers.add(new IF2Adapter(someIf2Implementation));
fetchData(dataReceivers);

public void fetchData(Collection<DataReceiver> receivers) {

  try {
    Data d = getSomeData();
    for (DataReceiver dr : receivers) {
      dr.dataReceived(d);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    for (DataReceiver dr : receivers) {
      dr.onError(e.getMessage());
    } 
  }
}
```

There are other patterns that may be applicable depending on your exact needs such as visitors or perhaps a chain-of-responsibility type pattern where you chain your receivers together in a linked list type construct and each one calls the next in a recursive construct - this would be nice as `fetchData` wouldn't need to know it is getting a collection, it just gets a reference to the *top* adapter in the chain.  So, `AbstractIFAdapter` would have a reference to another `AbstractIFAdapter`, let's call it `next`, and if the reference wasn't null, it would call `next.dataReceived(d)` in its own `dataReceived` method.  Similar idea as `ServletFilter`s where each filter gets the `ServletRequest` and then calls `chain.doFilter(request,response)`.

Comment: Very helpful answer. I ended up with a version of your first suggestion modified for my needs!